# Unable to move files to desktop

Tags: command-line, usb, nautilus, files, copy

I have just switched from Mac OS X to Ubuntu. The mac I'm using is macbook pro 2012. Ubuntu will not allow me to move files (folders, music, pdfs, etc.) from my usb stick to the desktop. When I attempt to drag and drop the files  from the usb onto the desktop, the files just bounce back into the usb folder.

I'm new to Linux, how can I solve this?

Comment: Some details may help us to understand. If you were using command, what was the command and error message you got. You've tagged `nautilus` so it was more likely using that, so where did you attempt to drag from? and to? did you get any error message?  Did you look in logs for clues?  (`dmesg` for example), and what release are you using? (recent release(s) need `sudo` to read `dmesg`)

Comment: What if you right-click and select "Move to..."?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did not use a command but rather plugged in the usb and attempted to drag and drop the files FROM the usb TO the desktop. I received no error msgs. When attempting to drag and drop, the files would simply bounce back into the usb folder. I have the most recent release of ubuntu. What does "sudo to read dmesg" mean?

Comment: When right clicking on the file, there is only "move to trash" available.

Comment: I've just tried on my system and also happens to me. From any random folder, with the desktop behind, drag and drop on the desktop will bounce back to nautilus window.

Comment: fernandezr you are correct. This is exactly what it does! Strange though, I downloaded ubuntu 18.0xx on my old 2008 macbook and was able to move files from the SAME usb/external drive without any problems. I don't know if the problem is with nautilus or if it's something else. I'm a complete novice with linux.

Comment: I've loaded ubuntu 20.04 on macbook pro 2012 and I'm having this problem. It has to be in the newer version of ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the clarifications you've made in the comments so that everyone can understand. Comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Also, do you have more than one screen by any chance? I can reproduce this (but on a different setup, so it might not be representative) only when I try to drag onto the Desktop shown on one of my secondary screens. It works if I drag onto the main screen.

Comment: terdon, I have only one screen open.

Comment: terdon, on my desktop is a folder with my account name on it. Apparently it was created by ubuntu when I installed it on my computer. In every way, it seems to be a duplicate of Nautilus. It's not in the taskbar but on the desktop. That said, I have just tried to drag and drop the usb files into this folder and they are loading, this very minute. Your question of two screens being open led me to look at that lone folder. Why it's there, I don't know, but it seems to solve the problem. The usb files are therefore not directly on the desktop but rather IN the folder that is on the desktop.

Comment: @terdon This is expected behaviour in 20.04. Please see my answer.

Comment: @heynnema thanks. By the way, there is no reason to leave a comment to the OP when you answer. The OP always gets an inbox notification when an answer is posted, so your comment just makes it that much easier to miss your answer (perhaps they only see your comment and not the answer notification). In other words, such comments are just noise in the best case and actively harmful in the worst case.

Comment: @terdon When I'm dealing with a new OP, I always try and educate them about accepting answers that successfully solve their problem. Then once accepted, I come back and delete my comment, to clean things up :-) (I've discussed this with the mods, and they agree that it's ok that way.)

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is expected behaviour in 20.04.x. The ~/Desktop, and desktop icons work differently than prior releases of Ubuntu. This is due to changes in GNOME and `Files` (Nautilus).

To copy files to the ~/Desktop, open TWO `Files` (Nautilus) windows. One open to the ~/Desktop, and the other one open to the folder that contains the items you wish to move. Then drag the desired items between the two open `Files` windows.

You can also create a folder on your ~/Desktop, called, say "Work in Progress", and then drag items directly into that new folder.

In `terminal`, you can also use the `cp` or `mv` commands to place items on the ~/Desktop.