# Moving a file in 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, files, transfer

I've recently upgraded Ubuntu to 20.4.1 LTS from 18.04.1 LTS through the Update Manager. Since then, I'm not able to move local files to a folder from the Desktop and vice versa. Though, a file transfer from a folder to an another one is possible. But not Desktop <----> Folder! Why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: GNOME did some weirdness with Desktop - it's no longer wrapped by the same mechanisms anymore and move/copy from Desktop to Folder is fubar.  I don't know of a workaround at the moment directly from the Desktop, but if you navigate to `/home/$USER/Desktop` in the Files application (Nautilus) you can once again move/copy from within the Files application from Desktop to a folder.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285291/unable-to-move-files-to-desktop/1285398#1285398